# Simplifying Notations in Recurrence Relation

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, recurrence-relation, big-o-notation, notation

In the CLRS book, section 4.4 they try to resolve the following recurrence:

$$T(n) = 3T\bigg(\bigg\lfloor \frac{n}{4} \bigg\rfloor\bigg) + \Theta(n^2)$$

Later, they write the same recurrence as

$$T(n) = 3T\bigg(\frac{n}{4}\bigg) + cn^2$$

And I do not understand why they change $\Theta(n^2)$ to $cn^2$

Mathematically speaking, Theta is a set, while $cn^2$ is a number.
Furthermore I know that $cn^2 \in \Theta(n^2)$ but not every polynomial in $\Theta(n^2)$ is in the form $cn^2$.

I'd enjoy to have a mathematical proof of what they did is correct, even if it's "easy to see", but I'm not satisfied with that.

**Update**
For whoever might be interested in the same question and seek for an answer, other than the given answers, I wrote a document here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/npvdnwyfxpcb

Comment: While your rigorous attitude are praiseworthy, it should not prevent you from reading a few more pages down the stream.  Your concern will be resolved.

Comment: @JohnL. Thank you for your comment. I might have an older edition or maybe I don't have enough neurons, but I don't see any explaination about this. The book proceeds to show that the result of this specific case is correct by doing a substitution, where I'd love to understand mathematically why in general it works :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider

$$T(n) -3T(\lfloor n/4 \rfloor) = \Theta(n^2) $$

which means that for some $N$, $n>N$ implies

$$T(n) -3T(\lfloor n/4 \rfloor) \le cn^2.$$

And if $n$ is a power of $4$, you may drop the floor:

$$T(n) -3T(n/4) \le cn^2.$$

These transformations are meant to make the resolution more tractable, and will not impair the final conclusions.

Comment: Thank you very much Yves. So you showed that $T(n) \leq 3T(n/4) + cn^2$ but in the book there's an equal sign, is that good anyways?

Comment: @AlessandroF: they are computing an upper bound.